# Two Google Chart on a single web page

Tags: html, google-visualization

I am trying to put two Google charts on a single web-page but can only get it to plot the first one and not the other. Can anyone look and see what I am doing wrong?

I am using two different divs for plotting, which I thought was the important step. I tried also using two different functions for the different plots but still could not get it to work.

I would be very thankful for useful suggestions.

thanks!!

Ayesha

```
<!--To change this template, choose Tools | Templates and open the template in the editor.-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['annotatedtimeline']});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart1);
        function drawChart1() {

            var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data1.addColumn('date', 'Date');
            data1.addColumn('number', 'Sold Pencils');
            data1.addColumn('string', 'title1');
            data1.addColumn('string', 'text1');
            data1.addColumn('number', 'Sold Pens');
            data1.addColumn('string', 'title2');
            data1.addColumn('string', 'text2');
            data1.addRows([
                [new Date(2008, 1 ,1), 30000, undefined, undefined, 40645, undefined, undefined],
                [new Date(2008, 1 ,2), 14045, undefined, undefined, 20374, undefined, undefined],
                [new Date(2008, 1 ,3), 55022, undefined, undefined, 50766, undefined, undefined],
                [new Date(2008, 1 ,4), 75284, undefined, undefined, 14334, 'Out of Stock','Ran out of stock on pens at 4pm'],
                [new Date(2008, 1 ,5), 41476, 'Bought Pens','Bought 200k pens', 66467, undefined, undefined],
                [new Date(2008, 1 ,6), 33322, undefined, undefined, 39463, undefined, undefined]
            ]);

            var chart1 = new google.visualization.AnnotatedTimeLine(document.getElementById('chart_div1'));
            chart1.draw(data1, {displayAnnotations: true});

            var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
                ['2004',  1000,      400],
                ['2005',  1170,      460],
                ['2006',  660,       1120],
                ['2007',  1030,      540]
            ]);

            var options = {
                title: 'Company Performance',
                vAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
            };

            var chart2 = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
            chart2.draw(data2, options);

        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p> Testing Google line chart tool </p>
    // Note how you must specify the size of the container element explicitly!
    <div id='chart_div1' style='width: 700px; height: 240px;'></div>

    <br> <br> <br> 

    <p> Testing another chart </p>
    <div id='chart_div2' style='width: 700px; height: 240px;'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Ayesha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include **corechart** when loading the packages.

```
google.load('visualization', '1', 
{'packages':['annotatedtimeline','corechart']});
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ng7ne/

Comment: That solves my problem ... for now. Expect more questions soon!! Thanks!!

Comment: Is there any way I can center the chart? I tried editing my CSS file to say .header{ text-align:center} but this is not text or an image so I don't know how to make the chart at the center. Any suggestions!!

Comment: Took so long because I was away from the computer right after answering. Although I don't know how it works, adding the margin requirement will center the div. `style='width: 700px; height: 240px; margin: 0px auto;'` http://jsfiddle.net/Ng7ne/2/ JSFiddle won't really show it properly because the frame is so small, you'll have to save it locally. Note the first chart won't appear centered properly because of the legend on the right, in that case you will have to manually set up a fixed width container div and use something like left: 200px in its style definition.